# Postgres "escape string constant" (e.g. E'foo\nbar') doesn't work with psql \copy

Tags: postgresql, psql, string-interpolation

I execute the following query in `psql` using an [escape string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

```
psql=# select E'foo\nbar' as example;
```

resulting in:

```
 example
---------
 foo    +
 bar
(1 row)
```

I write this query output to file using `\copy`:

```
psql=# \copy (select * from (select E'foo\nbar') as q) to 'test.txt'
COPY 1
```

and inspect the results:

```
bash$ cat test.txt
foo\nbar
```

but the output I expected is:

```
foo
bar
```

How can I get `\copy` to replace `\n` with a literal newline as expected? 
Alternately, what are other ways to get the result I want?

Comment: This is not an escaping issue, this is just [how the new-line character is printed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN71996) in the default `text` format.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? If that would be the whole issue, it would be much simpler f.ex. with `copy (values ('foo'), ('bar')) to stdout`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use a Postgres `COPY` instruction (not to be confused with psql's `\copy` meta-command) on the command line:

```
psql -h myhost -d mydatabase -c "COPY (select E'foo\nbar') TO STDOUT WITH CSV"
"foo
bar"
```

Comment: I think this is a difference between `FORMAT CSV` and `FORMAT TEXT`, not between `COPY` and `\copy`.